# Excel macro that creates footer containing last print date & last save date

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro using vba in excel 2013 which puts the last save date and the last print date in a footer. When I only print the document, the last print date changes in the correct manner. However, when I save the document my last save date and last print date are altered.

How do I stop my last print date from being affected when I save the document?

This is the code that I have been using:

```
Sub Footer()

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&9" & "Last Saved: " & ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(12) & Chr(13) & "Last Printed: " & ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(10)     
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = "&9" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & Chr(13) & ActiveWorkbook.Name & Chr(13) & ActiveSheet.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that it changes when you save the document? Because the last printing date also changes when you use the print preview (without actually printing) but it doesn't change on saving a document. I assume you check the footer by using the preview and this changes the print date.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know that but it makes sense now. That is the mistake that I have been making. Thank you Peh!